# Import Random throwing a multiple statements error

Tags: python, importerror, python-idle

I just started learning python and have immediately run into a road block while trying to build the Guess a Number game from one of Al Sweigart's books.

The code starts with this:

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0
```

Every time I run just that block of code in IDLE copy and pasted from the file editor, I get an error that says:
"SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement"

I can't for the life of me figure out why that code isn't working. I'm running Python 3.4 on Windows 11 and I'm not sure if it's a compatibility issue with the Python version being older or if I'm just doing something wrong. I appreciate the help in advance.

I first tried running the entire code block the book gives me, and when it threw that error I went through it and figured out it's not even getting past the first two lines.

Comment: I think it's a side effect of pasting multiple lines all at once.  Try pasting each line separately.

Comment: ...if you're just learning python, please also don't learn python3.4 - it's not just "old", but EOL almost 6 years ago. Python has gained a lot of wonderful features since that.

Answer (score 0):

In IDLE you need to execute code line by line. Or just save your code in .py file and run it by `python <filename>.py` in console.

Comment: Or paste the code into an IDLE editor, save it, and then run it from the editor with F5 (Run -> Run module on the menu).